# Detecting and correcting orientation of iPhone videos

Tags: iphone, ios, video, video-processing

I'm working on a video sharing app and we're having problems with videos uploaded from iPhones. Something about the meta data causes portrait videos to appear with the still frames incorrectly rotated sideways (into landscape).

Has anyone else seen this problem, and is there a way to modify the MOV files generated by iPhones so that they behave like other videos?